# Incorrect routing in routerLink Angular

Tags: angular

Something I'm confused with this routing.

app-routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'main',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./modules/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: '', component: HomeMenuComponent, children: [
    ],
  }];
```

file auth-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

But when in the template login-component.html I'm trying to follow the link:

```
<span class="link" routerLink="register" routerLinkActive="active-link">Зарегистрироваться</span>
```

it throws me to this address:

```
auth/login/register
```

Why is this happening?
On the one hand, that's right, I'm at the auth/login level. But on the other hand, when I look at other examples, they somehow turn out at such addresses. That's just I don't understand what I need to add for this.

Comment: Remove redirectTo: login part inside auth  routing. It will work after that

Comment: I spied this solution from another project. I just don't understand how to make the transition to "auth" automatically switch to the login-component, i.e. "auth/login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

"If the first segment begins with /, the router looks up the route from the root of the app.

If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router looks in the children of the current activated route."

You're probably at `auth/login` when you use the `routerLink='register'`, which as per the above quote, takes you to auth/login/register

Try `routerLink="/auth/register"`

Comment: Thank you this is how it works: "/auth/register"